# Flipped vertical coordinates with NSTableView nested within view-based NSTableView

Tags: cocoa, nstableview, nsscrollview

I have a view-based NSTableView (within a NSScrollView) which contains a row that has a another NSTableView within a NSScrollView. Everything works nicely until when I click on the innermost table view the coordinate system gets flipped vertically and makes it unusable. If I remove the inner NSScrollView (the superview of the inner table view) then I can click on the table without it getting flipped.

Does anyone have any idea what's causing this? I didn't find any other information on the problem but it appears that nesting NSScrollView is supported.

Thanks.